Firebase cloud function deploy error (javascript/nodejs)
I tried to deploy my cloud function like this
firebase deploy --only functions:api
I already haved deployed it many times, but now it's failing with following message

Error: Cloud Runtime Config is currently experiencing issues, which is preventing your functions from being deployed. Please wait a few minutes and then try to deploy your functions again.
Run firebase deploy --except functions if you want to continue deploying the rest of your project.


I'm on firebase-tools version 13.11.2
I checked the google cloud logs, but there is nothing logged.
I did an firebase login --reauth, but this also did not worked.

There is no information on the Google Cloud Dashboard page about whether Cloud Runtime might really have a problem at the moment.
Is there something else that i can try?

Found the error....
i needed to change the project via
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
It's a bit strange because, i set the project beforehand through firebase.
